# specify variable as some kind of enum in dart

Tags: dart, enums

Here's a little fun class:

```
abstract class Concept {
  late Enum option;
  String get name => option.name;
}
```

and you might implement it like this:

```
enum FeeOption {
  fast,
  standard,
  slow,
}
class FastFeeRate extends Concept {
  FeeOption option = FeeOption.fast;
}
print(FastFeeRate().name); // 'fast'
```

but then you get an error:

```
FastFeeRate.option=' ('void Function(FeeOption)') isn't a valid override of 'Concept.option=' ('void Function(Enum)').
```

So, how do you specify a variable as any kind of enum, not Enum itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `Concept` has a mutable (`late`, but that doesn't matter) field with type `Enum`. That means it has a *setter* named `option=` with an argument type of `Enum`.

The subclass `FastFeeRate` is a subclass. It has another field (your class has two fields!) also named `option`, which has a setter with an argument type of `FastFeeRate`.

That's not a valid override. The subclass setter must accept all arguments that the superclass setter does, but it doesn't accept all `Enum` values.

What you might have intended to do is:

```dart
abstract class Concept<T extends Enum> {
  T option;
  Concept(this.option);
  String get name => option.name;
}
class FastFeeRate extends Concept<FeeOption> {
  FastFeeRate() : super(FeeOption.fast);
}
```

or

```dart
abstract class Concept<T extends Enum> {
  abstract T option;
  String get name => option.name;
}
class FastFeeRate extends Concept<FeeOption> {
  FastFeeRate option = FeeOption.fast;
}
```

depending on whether you want to define the field in the superclass or the subclass (but make sure to only define a concrete field in *one* of them).